# MySQL individual counts, from multiple tables, grouped by date

Tags: mysql

I have multiple MySQL tables, within one database, which each record transactions performed. Each table has a DATETIME field to record when each transaction occurred.

How do I construct a MySQL query, or procedure, to produce the count of transactions from each table, grouped by each date?

I want to see each days total from the start of the current month up to, and including, the current day.

In each table a row represents one transaction. So the columns are just the count of rows in each table, for each date.

E.g running such query, Today, would yield a table like;

26/04/2016 Total A Transactions, Total B Transactions,  ...

25/04/2016 Total A Transactions, Total B Transactions,  ...

....

01/04/2016 Total A Transactions, Total B Transactions, ...

Sample schema;

CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
    `uuid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `creationTime` DATETIME NOT NULL, ..

CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
    `uuid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `creationTime` DATETIME NOT NULL, ..

...

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP BY clause` ? Can you also update your question with your database schema and possibly some sample data ?

Comment: Hi Maximus2012, example, truncated table schema added.

Comment: Do you really need multiple tables here or could you possibly combine them into a single table or something like that ?

Comment: Hi Maximus, The tables are multi tens of millions of rows. I'll remember to add that detail, and more detail in general when I next ask questions. Thank you for highlighting the need for extra detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that tableA has at least one transaction a day.

```
select create_time, total_a_transaction, total_b_transaction, ...
from

(select date(creationTime) create_time, count(*) total_a_transaction
from tableA 
where year(creationTime) = year(curdate()) 
and month(creationTime) = month(curdate())
group by date(creationTime)) transaction_a

left join

(select date(creationTime) create_time, count(*) total_b_transaction
from tableB 
where year(creationTime) = year(curdate()) 
and month(creationTime) = month(curdate())
group by date(creationTime)) transaction_b

using (create_time)

left join ...
```

Comment: Thankyou Tin, That is just what I needed and works well.

Answer (score 2):

```
select date(my_date), count(*), 'tableA' fromc tableA 
where month(my_date) = month(curdate())
AND year(my_date) = Year(curdate())
group by date(my_date)
union 
select date(my_date), count(*), 'tableB' fromc tableB 
where month(my_date) = month(curdate())
AND year(my_date) = Year(curdate())    
group by date(my_date)
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, Its for multiple tables. I have just updated the question to, hopefully, make the multiple tables element clearer.

Comment: you may need filter for 'year'

Comment: @Tin added filter for current year

Comment: Hi ScaisEdge, just marked Tin's answer as the one. It came in milliseconds before your with the date filters.